# Windows Azure VM (Mac) to build Ionic app for ios devices

Tags: ios, macos, azure, ionic-framework, ionic2

I'm developing Ionic2/Angular apps using an Ionic framework.I have no problem with Android.My question here is, can I use Windows Azure VM (Mac) to build my app for ios devices?

I have `Win 8.1` OS.

**Note:** This is not a duplicate question about the same kind of questions here.I have a specific question where I need to know about can I use the Azure VM to build Ionic apps for ios devices. I don't like any methods which are not Legal.

Comment: does azure legally support Mac VMs ? You can only if it does ... Basically, you will need XCode to build and export the iOS version (while you can develop app on any platforms).

Comment: Oh .. That means can't we have Mac VMs on Azure platform? @PrashantGhimire

Comment: Not sure about that, a quick google did not show any significant result. Apple is pretty reluctant about allowing that to happen ...

Comment: There's no support for Mac on Azure VMs.

Comment: Hmm.. I'm doing some R&D about this and will let you know about that later here @PrashantGhimire Hope we'll have a better legal alternative.Will see  :)

Comment: Yes, you're right. Hope we'll have better legal alternative.I'm working(R&D) on it and will share that later :) @ThiagoCustodio

Comment: There are many services that offer this for you: http://www.macincloud.com/features/tools/tools

Comment: Yes, you're right.I think that is the best service which we can use for this task.Do you have any experience with this service or? @ThiagoCustodio

Comment: I am not mobile dev, but Azure / Web dev.

Comment: Would you like to put that as an answer? I can close this then :) @ThiagoCustodio

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not possible to use MacOs on Azure Virtual Machines, you should use another 3rd party service to compile your Ios Apps:

Examples:

http://www.macincloud.com/features/tools/tools

https://www.macstadium.com/

Answer (score 2):

you could use a hosted macOS agent on Azure DevOps [hosted agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/hosted)