# Set up Mac OS environment for iOS development in Microsoft Azure VDI

Tags: android, ios, macos, azure

I want to set up Mac OS environment for iOS development in Microsoft Azure VDI.

Can anyone share the steps or share details on the feasibility.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it is possible today. Here is a similar question, and seems like it is not possible to run MacOS on Azure: [Windows Azure VM (Mac) to build Ionic app for ios devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42848516/windows-azure-vm-mac-to-build-ionic-app-for-ios-devices)

And it seems like it is not even legal to run Mac OS on any cloud provider:
https://superuser.com/questions/690224/is-there-a-way-to-install-mac-os-on-an-azure-virtual-machine-or-any-cloud-vm-f

But, you can up vote these requests on azure forums, and there is a chance that it will be possible in the future: 
https://feedback.azure.com/forums/216843-virtual-machines/suggestions/13826655-mac-os-x-virtual-machines

https://feedback.azure.com/forums/216843-virtual-machines/suggestions/6655478-provide-a-way-to-run-mac-based-remote-build-agents

However if you just want to build you iOS app and you don't need your own VM you can do that:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/languages/xcode?view=azure-devops